# Formatting a string with elements in a list based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

So I've created a series of grammers for use within a method in a class I've created. Each list can be n elements long so placing each word via list index is prettings straight forward `wordlist[1:]`, however I need to use an `|` operator and that can't be done with explicit string indexes (at least I think so). This is what I've written so far:

```
noun_types = ['port', 'harbor', 'harbour']
target_pronouns = ['rotterdam', 'moscow']

grammer1 = (
                F"""
                S ->  Det N P NP
                P -> P
                NP -> '{target_pronouns[0]}' | '{target_pronouns[1]}'
                Det -> 'the' | 'a'
                P -> 'of'
                N -> '{noun_types[0]}' | '{noun_types[1]}' | '{noun_types[2]}'
                """)
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass a list of n number of pronouns and nouns and have the strings be formatted with each element without explicit string indexes, so something like this:

```
noun_types = ['port', 'harbor', 'harbour']
target_pronouns = ['rotterdam', 'moscow']

grammer1 = (
                F"""
                S ->  Det N P NP
                P -> P
                NP -> '{target_pronouns[range(0, len(target_pronouns))]}'
                Det -> 'the' | 'a'
                P -> 'of'
                N -> '{noun_types[range(0, len(target_pronouns))]}'
                """)
```

However, I'm not sure how to implment the `|` operator, much less any conditional formatting when doing string formatting. The grammer formatting is based on nltk's grammer constructor used in this context:

```
from nltk.parse.generate import generate
from nltk import CFG

grammar = CFG.fromstring(grammer1)
for sentence in generate(grammar, n = 10, depth = 5):
words = ' '.join(sentence)
```

Its a bit of a confusing question, so I'm happy to try and clarify any confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think there is a hacky way to do that: escape your strings with `'` character beforehands, and then just plug them into your f-string using `" | ".join()`.

Add both `'` before and after each string of your input lists:

```
noun_types = [f"'{noun}'" for noun in noun_types]
target_pronouns = [f"'{pronoun}'" for pronoun in target_pronouns]
```

Now you can just put them into the f-string using `" | ".join()`. This will work regardless sizes of your input lists, no need for indices.

```
print(f"""
NP -> {' | '.join(target_pronouns)}
N -> {' | '.join(noun_types)}
""")
```

Output:

```
NP -> 'rotterdam' | 'moscow'
N -> 'port' | 'harbor' | 'harbour'
```

Another solution, if things get more complicated, could be to go into [Jinja templating](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/) although right now it seems sufficient to hack it and avoid an extra library.

Comment: This is perfect, I was trying to implement something similar by just adding the `|` into the list I just didn't know if there was a more pythonic way of do it, now I do thank you!

Comment: Great! Indeed, seeing from your `words = ' '.join(sentence)` I thought you may be close to solving the question given you had the right tools.